# Lost my Destiny Mission?

Tags: destiny

Okay, so I've been playing Destiny recently, and I am on the moon. I have completed the mission 'The Shine of Oryx,' three times, and have not recieved a new story mission and I am level ten. I doubt this will help at all, but I am playing on a PS4. I think I may have lost it.

Also, I have watched a Youtuber play The Shrine of Oryx, and he also has a different level eight story mission called The Chamber of Night, which I do not have unlocked.

I am trying to ask if I am supposed to get a mission straight after this, and if I do not, what do I do?

Comment: what are you asking here? If you should recieve a new mission straight after? How to pick up discarded missions? Where you should go after shrine of oryx? You need to give us more then "I did this and then this happened" before we can really try to help.

Comment: He's saying he completed a story mission and didn't unlock the next story mission for some reason.

Comment: Is there an item you have to take to the Tower, by any chance?

Comment: Is there a way to check?

Comment: If you go to the tower, and you have to talk to the Speaker, or the Vanguard people or something, then that may be it. It's been a long, long time since I've played, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: If you open the menu and go to the Quests tab, do you have anything there indicating what you need to do next?

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki there is no quest after The Shrine of Oryx. When you unlocked the shrine mission you should have also unlocked another mission called the *Chamber of Night*. This is the one which you need to complete in order to unlock the next quest in the story entitled *A Stranger's Call*.

Check either the galaxy map to see if you have mission available, or you can open your quest page in the menu.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though, I have not unlocked the Chamber of Night, therefore, something is wrong. Would you happen to know why? Also, I have only recently done a patrol for the first time, could this be why?

Comment: If you have no quests on the quest page, or mission exclamation points on the galaxy map, you can check the kiosk to the right of the Vanguards sitting at the table in the tower. This kiosk will show any quests you may have accidentally cancelled.